# Proof: $\exists z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that every sub-sequence of $(z_n)_n$ has a convergent sub-sequence with the limit $z$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Claim:**

Let $(z_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb C$ such that the subsequences $(z_{2n})_n$, $(z_{2n+1})_n$ and $(z_{3n})_n$ are convergent. Then there $\exists z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that every sub-sequence of $(z_n)_n$ has a convergent sub-sequence with the limit $z$.

**My attempt:**

Let $z_{{n_k}_k}$ be a sub-sub-sequence of $(z_n)_n$. It is $n_{k_k}\geq k$ for every $k$. Its easy to prove via induction, since $n_1\geq 1$ and$n_{k_k}\geq k$ imply that $n_{{k}_{k+1}}> n_{k_k} \geq k$ and hence $n_{{k}_{k+1}}\geq k+1$.

What do you think?

Comment: are there any assumptions on the sequence $(z_n)_n$?
if not, then this is clearly false. Take for example $z_n=n$.

Comment: $(z_{2n})_n$ , $(z_{2n+1})_n$ and $(z_{3n})_n$ are convergent

Comment: Include the complete statement of the problem in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You should start by saying "Let $z_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers."

Comment: Ok, but is the rest ok?

Comment: I edited it a bit.

Comment: and what about the proof?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(z_{6n})$ is a subsequence of both $(z_{2n})$ and $(z_{3n})$, then converges to the same limit of both sequences, since they are convergent. Therefore $(z_{2n})$ and $(z_{3n})$ converge to the same limit $z$.

Use the same argument for the subsequence $(z_{3(2n+1)})$, and conclude that $(z_{2n})$ and $(z_{2n+1})$ converge to the same limit, and then prove that the sequence $(z_n)$ converge to $z$.